# How to change the value of an attribute in Grakn

Tags: graph, entity, vaticle-typeql, vaticle-typedb

In Grakn, I want to change the value of a `name` attribute that's attached to an `entity`.

At the moment I am doing this (see below), which is just deleting the attribute and then inserting a new one to the country entity.

```
match
$b isa country, has name "Old Name";
$a isa name; 
$a val contains "Old Name";
delete $a;

insert 
$b has name "New Name";
```

I can't find any documentation on how to actually edit just the value of the attribute.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, that is currently the way to do it. The next release will simplify the process with a new `via` syntax. With regards to updating the value of a resource that is not allowed. Resource values are immutable. We will in the future make it simpler to change the resources which are linked to entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually for now, I am not sure you can... I did not find any solution, if you do a `match`... `insert` you will add a new ressource and you need to delete the old one. It will not be update. I am sure it is coming in a new feature though ;)

do not forget to `commit` your `delete` transaction. All modification to the graph need to be committed.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that it is important to understand in Grakn is that attributes with the same type and value are shared between owners.

This means that **deleting an attribute belonging to a specific concept will also delete it for all other concepts**.

Here are a few examples:

*Example 1*

```
insert $x isa company, has name "grakn";
insert $x isa website, has name "grakn";
```

Here we have inserted two concepts which share a name.

```
match $x isa company, has name $n; $n "grakn"; delete $n;
```

Now the `name` `grakn` has been deleted, which means it no longer exists in the database, so as a result you will find that it has also been deleted for the website.

*Example 2*

```
insert $x isa company, has business-name "grakn", has company-number 01234;
insert $x isa company, has business-name "grakn", has company-number 56789;
insert $x isa website, has website-name "grakn";
```

In this case we have inserted two different companies which share the business-name "grakn", and a website with website-name "grakn".

```
match $x isa company, has business-name $n, has company-number 01234; $n "grakn"; delete $n;
```

In this case the `website-name` "grakn" isn't deleted, but the shared name for the companies will be.

*Example 3* - **probably the example you want**

```
insert $x isa company, has name "grakn";
insert $x isa website, has name "grakn";
```

As in ex1, we add a company and website which share an attribute (because the attribute type **and** value are the same).

This time we only want to delete the association between the attribute between the company and the attribute, and leave the website untouched:

```
match $x isa company, has name "grakn" via $r; delete $r;
```

This finds the relationship, `$r`, which is that actual connection behind the scenes that links the attribute to its owner, and deletes it.

Compared to example 1, in this case you'll find that the website keeps its name, since the attribute itself wasn't deleted, only one of the connections to it.

*The solution*

To update an attribute requires an extra step, because we need to add a new attribute to replace the one we remove. When doing this we need to make sure we refer to the same company (instance) that we removed the name (attribute) from. Otherwise, how do you re-find the company whose name you removed in order to add a new name?

We can do this with a `match... insert` query, followed by an `insert` query:

```
match $x isa company, has name "grakn";
insert $x has name "new-name";

match $x isa company, has name "grakn" via $r; delete $r;
```